# Getting a branch from github

Tags: git, github

I have a master branch and a version2 branch in github. From the command line in ubuntu how do I retrieve the version 2 branch? I keeps pulling the master branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution:

Assuming your starting from scratch, first clone the github repo.  Github gives nice directions on how to do this when you create a report.  Once you have it cloned, type `git checkout -b version2 origin/version2`

## Explanation:

When you clone a repo you automatically get references and all of the commits for each of the branches that are in that repository.  The `git checkout -b localBranchName remote/branchName` command tells git that you want to create, and checkout, a new local branch that will "track" the remote branch `remote/branchName`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `git checkout`:

```
git checkout version2
```

Comment: If I have three repos< from the commad line, how do I know with repo?  Is there a earlier step?  e.g. 1) select repo 2) checkout version2.  I am mussing that first step from the command line

Comment: You have to be in the folder of the repo you want to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Run `git remote update` to pull down a local copy of all changes in all branches in your remote repository. Then run `git checkout version2` to create a local branch that tracks your upstream version2 branch. When you run `git pull` while on version2, it will pull down changes from your upstream version2 and merge them in.

Comment: I get this error: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git.  I have three repos.  Repo 1 has the version2.  Do I clone first? I am new to git.

Comment: @Tampa: If you're brand new to git, you might want to read some tutorials before diving right in. Here is github's set of guides: http://help.github.com/

Comment: I with I had time but I a recovering from a crash of my ubuntu virtual machine

Comment: git is sufficiently powerful enough that if you're not sure what you're doing, it's easy to do the wrong thing and end up in a worse state than when you started. The time you spend now doing a little bit of learning will save you much more time in the long run.